# 2D fused Lasso with Matlab CVX

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, convex-optimization, cvx

I wrote a 2D fused lasso code here.

```
[m n] = size(circle);
cvx_begin
    variable theta(m, n);
    minimize( norm(circle-theta, 'fro'));
    subject to
        sum(sum(abs(theta(:,1:n-1)-theta(:,2:n)))) == 0;
        sum(sum(abs(theta(1:m-1,:)-theta(2:m,:)))) == 0;
cvx_end
```

Weirdly, the program report,

> > In cvxprob (line 28)   In cvx_begin (line 41)  Error using cvxprob/newcnstr (line 192) Disciplined convex programming error:
> >     Invalid constraint: {convex} == {constant}
>
> Error in  ==  (line 12) b = newcnstr( evalin( 'caller', 'cvx_problem',
>   '[]' ), x, y, '==' );

After I remove `abs()` in the constraint, the program could run, but that's not what constraints I expect to be.

Comment: huh what. That is not MATLAB code, is it?

Comment: It is using the cvx package under MATLAB

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try stacking the matrices into vectors, then use L1 norm. In CVX, it's just norm(variable, 1). It will do the same as you wrote here: sum of absolute elementary-wise differences.